# Cannot run postgres request from python 2.7 on MACOS mojave

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, odbc, macos-mojave

I'm trying to run python 2.7 code (Queries) on Postgres DB. Regarding the version of pyodbc installed either it crashes python or I got problem relative to UTF8. Si I cannot use my python code.

I installed python 2.7, pyodbc 3.0.7 on MAC Mojave 10.14 (Then I get UTF8 error).

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22021', '[22021] ERROR: invalid byte sequence for
>   encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x81 0xa9;\nError while executing the query (1)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)')

I installed python 2.7 pyodbc > 3.0.7 on MAC Mojave 10.14 (Then Python is crashing)

I should be able to connect to my database using ODBC driver.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend installing Python 3.X and see if that works. It is more updated and many new libraries are utilizing it more and more - will provide better use in the future.

Comment: I cannot because this is a requirement on the project I am working on.